# How do sacrifices affect the Temple of the Sun God?

Tags: bloons-td-5

So after round 101 I Upgraded a "Sun God" Super Monkey to a "Temple of the Sun God" Super Monkey. If you didn't know this makes it consume, or "sacrifice" as the game calls it, all the surrounding towers gaining different qualities dependent on the towers "sacrificed".

My Temple consumed a very large of amount of towers of every kind, and it only acquired 3 noticeable abilities doing so. One was it shot out a missile, another it threw out tornadoes and it shot an Area of Effect of Razors (this didn't make sense since my tack towers had been upgraded to shoot fire). I did however have a missile turret (although it had been upgraded differently then the missile the temple was shooting), and I did have a monkey apprentice that shot out tornadoes.

I also noticed it did significantly more damage and the Temple's range covered the entire map almost. So my question is, **How does the Temple of the Sun God determine its new abilities, range, and damage depending on the amount and variety of towers it has sacrificed?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's [a bunch of information on the temple](http://bloons.wikia.com/wiki/Temple_of_the_Monkey_God) including how to get a *perfect* temple with every possible attack and ability. I can't say exactly what happened in your case however, since I cannot see what it looked like before sacrificing everything.

Unique Abilities, and Sacrifices Needed to Get Them. (Taken from link)

> To build the most powerful temple, sacrifice the following nine maxed
>   towers:
>
> - To get longer freeze time, sacrifice ***Ice Tower - Viral Frost***. (4 - x)
> - To get larger freeze radius, sacrifice ***Ice Tower - Absolute Zero***. (x - 4)
> - To get more corrosive glue splatter, sacrifice ***Glue Gunner - Bloon  Liquefier***. (4 - x)
> - To get larger glue splatter, sacrifice ***Glue Gunner - Glue Striker***. (x - 4)
> - To get stronger tornadoes, sacrifice ***Monkey Apprentice - Tempest Tornado***. (4 - x)
> - To get larger tornadoes, sacrifice ***Monkey Apprentice - Summon Phoenix***. (x - 4)
> - To get greater missile damage against ceramic bloons, sacrifice ***Bomb Tower - MOAB Assassin***. (x - 4)
> - To get six missiles per 1.5 seconds, sacrifice ***Mortar Tower - Big One*** (4 - x) or Artillery Battery (x - 4).
> - To get stronger sun rays, sacrifice Super Monkey - Technological Terror. (x - 4)
>
> Note that sacrificing other tower types duplicate the 16 blade volleys per second benefit provided by sacrificing the Super Monkey - Technological Terror.

Comment: ill add a picture later.

Comment: Perhaps you can summarize the information into your answer in case the link one day goes dead?

Comment: There are 2 different opinions. One is that what matter is only the kind of sacrifice and the price. The other is the upgrade matter.

Answer (score 10):

The answer in the wiki link is weak, but it links to a [forum post](https://web.archive.org/web/20180924211340/http://archive.ninjakiwi.com/Forum/showthread.php/17674-Temple-of-the-Monkey-God-The-Complete-Guide) that explains

> To create the most powerful Temple, you need to sacrifice:
>
> Missiles: $24000 ($30000) of Mortar and/or Bomb towers. Missiles fire in groups of 5. Each can hit 100 bloons, in a blast area similar to a Big One mortar.
>       Ice Bolts: $24000 ($30000) of Ice towers
>       The bolt explodes on impact, popping and freezing nearby bloons.
>       Glue Globs: $24000 ($30000) of Glue Gunners
>       The rate of fire, splash, and dissolve-speed are all about twice what you'd get from a level 2/2 Glue Gunner.
>       Tornados: $24000 ($30000) of Apprentices
>       They can pop bloons and blow them back towards the entrance.
>       Blades: $24000 ($30000) of any other towers (dart/tack/sniper/boomerang/ninja/pirate/ace/super/village/farm/dartling/spike) or 1 Special Agent
>       16 spinning blades fly out in a circle. Each can hit 40 bloons.
>       Faster Secondary Attacks: Jungle Drums*
>       Speeds up everything except plasma by 15%. You can get the same effect by placing Jungle Drums near the Temple, so this sacrifice is optional.
>       Additional Target: Monkey Fort*
>       Each shot (plasma, missile, etc.) can hit 1 additional target. You can get the same effect by placing a Fort near the Temple, so this sacrifice is optional.
>       More Cash: Monkey Town*
>       Temple earns 50% more cash from pops. (You'll get the Drums power too, of course.) There isn't much cash from pops after level 50, though. You can get the same effect by placing a Town near the Temple, so this sacrifice is optional.

The $24,000 is the sell for price while the $30,000 is the purchase price.  The sell for price only matters in that it is easier to determine for an already built tower.  The tiers are actually based on the purchase prices of the towers.

Note that other than a Monkey Village, the actual abilities of the sacrificed towers don't matter.  For example, sacrificing 2/4 Apprentices gives Tornadoes even though they don't have Tornadoes themselves.  Or as in the question's example, sacrificing Rings of Fire (4/0+) can give blades even though blades are from the other improvement path (blades also come from other types of towers).

The post also gives a full breakdown of the tiers for each class of ability (based on purchase price; sell for prices would be 80% lower):

### Glue

```
$1-$1300: Fires soaking glue splatters (Credit to HelmsDeep) every 16 frames (Credit to Aresake?)
$1301-$3999: Glue splatters are now corrosive (Credit to HelmsDeep)
$4000-$9999: Fires larger glue splatters (Credit to HelmsDeep)
$10000-$29999: Greatly increases corrosiveness of the glue (Credit to HelmsDeep)
$30000+: Unknown
Missing info: Effects of $30000+, popping power of splatters, fire rate changes in splatters if any, exact corrosiveness of $10000-$29999
```

### Tornadoes

```
$1-$1300: Fires small whirlwinds (Credit to HelmsDeep) every 38 frames (Credit to Aresake?)
$1301-$3999: Fires large whirlwinds (Credit to HelmsDeep)
$4000-$9999: Fires small tornadoes (Credit to HelmsDeep)
$10000-$29999: Fires large tornadoes (Credit to HelmsDeep)
$30000+: Tornadoes pop bloons once more before blowing (Credit to Underrated1)
Missing info: Popping power of tornadoes
```

### Blades

```
$1-$1300: Fires volleys of 16 darts with 20 popping power (Credit to HelmsDeep) every 25 frames (Credit to Aresake?) that pop 2 layers (credit to Underrated1)
$1301-$3999: Each dart pops 25 bloons (Credit to HelmsDeep) for 3 layers each (credit to Underrated1)
$4000-$9999: Fires blades that pop 30 bloons (Credit to HelmsDeep) for 4 layers each (credit to Underrated1)
$10000-$29999: Each blade pops 35 bloons (Credit to HelmsDeep)
$30000+: Each blade pops 40 bloons (Credit to HelmsDeep)
Missing Info: Fire rate changes in darts/blades if any
```

### Ice Blasts

```
$1-$1300: Fires very large ice bombs (Credit to Underrated1) every 60 frames (Credit to Aresake?)
$1301-$3999: Ice bombs now have Snap Freeze (Credit to HelmsDeep)
$4000-$9999: Ice bombs now feature an incredibly long freeze (Credit to HelmsDeep)
$10000-$29999: Ice bombs effect an area of 650 pixels (Credit to Rohan)
$30000+: Duration of freeze appears to be roughly 60 frames (Credit to Rohan)
Missing info: Effects of $30000+, popping power of ice blasts, fire rate changes in ice blasts if any, exact duration of freeze
```

### Missiles

```
$1-$1300: Fires a missile with popping power of 100 (Credit to HelmsDeep) every 31 frames (Credit to Aresake?)
$1301-$3999: Fires two missiles at once (Credit to HelmsDeep)
$4000-$9999: Fires three missiles at once (Credit to HelmsDeep)
$10000-$29999: Fires four missiles at once (Credit to HelmsDeep)
$30000+: Fires five missiles at once
Missing info: Fire rate changes in missiles if any
```

Plasma tiers come from all classes of towers.  Note that towers effectively count twice.  Once for the secondary abilities and once for the plasma.

### Plasma

> "Power Levels"
>
> ```
> Level 1: =<$1300 - No plasma bonus  
> Level 2: $1301-$3999 - 1 layer of damage  
> Level 3: $4000-$9999 - No plasma bonus  
> Level 4: $10,000-$29,999 - 1 layer of damage  
> Level 5: >=$30,000 - 1 layer of damage
> ```
>
> The Temple's basic plasma bolts can each hit 50 targets and pop 3 layers (2 layers vs MOAB/BFB/ZOMG). For every "power level" you have of missiles, ice, glue, tornado, or blades, the plasma can hit 5 additional targets the best Temple plasma can hit (50 + 5x5 + 4x5 + 4x5 + 4x5 + 5x5) = 160 bloons. With Tier 5 the plasma bonus adds up to (3 +3 +3 +3 +3 +3) = 18 layers of damage, but caps at 15.
>
> If there are enough targets, the best Plasma can do up to...
>   1932 damage (layers) per second to MOAB-class bloons, OR
>   8372 damage (red bloon equivalents) per second to Ceramic bloons.
>   Actual damage in super-high-level games is about 4500 DPS.
>
> For comparison: All together, the secondary (power) attacks can do about 100 DPS, but actual damage is more like 40 DPS.

Range is not affected by the towers sacrificed.  A temple has a pretty large range to start (greater than the base Super Monkey range) and can get more range with the /1 and /2 upgrades.  There's also a bug with how Monkey Beacons work that makes it give more range if the beacon is built after the tower gets its own range upgrades rather than before.

Answer (score 0):

Apprentices do tornadoes
Bombs/Mortars do explosions
Glue Gunners do glue splatters
Ice towers freeze
Any other tier 4 does blade

look here for details
http://bloons.wikia.com/wiki/Temple_of_the_Monkey_God/Sacrifices

Answer (score -1):

I notice that by sacrificing bloon chipper and monkey engineer or possibly on fo them makes the temple shoot darts.

Answer (score -3):

The other towers upgraded makes piercing and shoot darts or blades.

Comment: Hi Ethan, This answer doesn't seem very clear. Perhaps you could edit it to explain further?